# Como tornar compatíveis os objetos vindos de duas classes diferentes, derivadas da mesma interface?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, classes, interface, injeção-de-dependência

Tenho uma interface (chamarei de `ICliente`) que é utilizada como contrato entre uma aplicação e uma DLL.

```
public interface ICliente
{
    int Id {get; set;}
    string Nome {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Essa interface é implementada tanto do lado da aplicação quanto do lado da DLL da mesma forma, com o mesmo nome, etc. A única diferença é que no lado da DLL existem alguns *annotations*.

```
//Lado da Aplicação
public class Cliente: ICliente
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public string Nome {get; set;}
    ...
}

//Lado da DLL
public class Cliente: ICliente
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public string Nome {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Quando eu tento passar um `object` da aplicação para a DLL, o seguinte erro ocorre:

> "Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'Aplicacao.Model.Cliente'
>   no tipo 'Biblioteca.Model.Cliente'"

Mesmo quando meu método de atribuição recebe um `ICliente` como parâmetro (exemplo abaixo), no momento em que eu tento fazer um cast desse objeto `ICliente` para o `Cliente` da DLL, ele da a mesma mensagem.

```
//Lado da Aplicação
public bool Salvar(ICliente objClienteApp )
{
    ...
    return DLL.Salvar((Cliente) objClienteApp); //<-- Aqui ocorre o erro
}

//Lado da DLL
public bool Salvar (Cliente objClienteDLL)
{
    ...
}
```

Pra mim, por fazerem parte de uma mesma interface eles deveriam se conversar, mas a pratica mostrou o contrário.

Estou tentando evitar fazer um "De-Para" entre objetos, pois isso daria um trabalhão.

Existe alguma forma de tornarmos esses objetos compatíveis?

Comment: O que exatamente não ficou claro, @Maniero?

Comment: Sua resposta mostra que a pergunta nada tinha a ver com o que queria.

Comment: A resposta (ao meu ver) mostra o erro conceitual que eu estava cometendo ao tentar compatibilizar duas classes diferentes. A solução do meu problema foi usar a injeção de dependência (que antes eu só tinha ouvido falar) para obter o resultado que eu esperava.

Comment: Isso nada tem a ver com DI, a resposta não fala sobre o seu problema, e isso só mostra que não entendeu o problema ainda, além da sua resposta não ajudar ninguém, nem a você mesmo, ainda que ache assim.

Comment: Maniero, já esta implementado. Tenho uma aplicação que utiliza uma DLL como um tipo de "plugin de acesso a dados" utilizando injeção de dependência para manter. A aplicação chama a DLL e a DLL retorna os dados conforme o contrato das interfaces envolvidas. Ao meu ver, esta resolvido (e realmente esta, pois o programa esta aqui no meu notebook rodando). Por que você acha que não tem a ver com DI? Tem outra forma mais correta de se fazer isso? Se tiver, me de uma dica.

Comment: Eu respondo, você ignorou. Achou sua solução e se for esse só você poderia dizer algo sobre isso, daí o motivo da pergunta não estar clara. Qualquer resposta postada pode estar certa ou errada, ninguém sabe qual é a dúvida real (talvez só você, talvez nem você), só deu pra ter certeza disso depois que postou a resposta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96695/discussion-between-alexql-and-maniero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que andei analisando, o que faltou no meu código foi a tal da [injeção de dependência](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_depend%C3%AAncia).

Meu erro (segundo minha analise) foi querer referenciar um objeto de uma classe a partir de outro objeto de outra classe (conforme já disseram), porem posso referenciar qualquer objeto através da interface que as classes desses objetos implementaram.

O [exemplo a seguir](https://blog.submain.com/c-interface-definition-examples/) mostra mais ou menos a ideia que quero por em pratica:

```
// define an interface
public interface ILogger
{
    void LogError(Error error);
}

// implement ILogger by logging to a file
public class FileLogger : ILogger
{
    public void LogError(Error error)
    {
        File.WriteLine(someFileUri, error.ToString());
    }
}


// implement ILogger by logging to Debug log
public class DebugLogger : ILogger
{
    public void LogError(Error error)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(error.ToString());
    }
}

// program to the ILogger interface
public class MyProgram
{
    private ILogger _log;

    // inject whichever ILogger into this class via constructor
    public MyProgram(ILogger log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            StartInternal();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Error error = Error.FromException(ex, Context);
            _logError(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Nesse código acima, posso passar para o construtor "MyProgram" tanto um objeto da classe "FileLogger" quanto um objeto da classe "DebugLogger" pois ambos implementam a mesma interface ILogger

A diferença é que no meu caso, uma das classes que implementam a interface em questão esta numa DLL.

Gostaria da opinião de vocês sobre a resposta, se ela faz sentido, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Tem pelo menos dois problemas aí.

## Duplicidade de definições do mesmo objeto

Um deles é ter dois `Cliente` sendo que é o mesmo objeto. Essa definição deveria ser canônica, isto vai causar vários problemas. A maioria das dificuldades de manutenção em um software são advindos de modelagem errada (esta em específico eu nunca tinha visto). Se por acaso eles seriam coisas diferentes nunca deveriam estar conflitando. Corrija este erro conceitual que é a raiz do problema e não terá o erro de compilação. Não tente corrigir de outra forma porque estará apenas mudando o erro de lugar (pode até funcionar, mas ainda estará errado).

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

## Abstração do concreto

O outro erro é usar um *cast*, quase todas as vezes que faz isso é porque modelou errado (as maiorias das exceções são por causa do legado já que o .NET modelou algumas coisas erroneamente na primeira versão). Se precisa mesmo fazer um *cast* é porque está recebendo o tipo errado, então receba ali o `Cliente` e não o `ICliente`. Está fazendo um *cast* para acessar outros membros, então não á interface que precisa acessar, é o objeto, então o parâmetro deve ser a classe e não a interface.

Eu nem vou falar para usar o *namespace* correto para pegar o `Cliente` correto para esse caso porque ainda manteria o erro de ter o mesmo objeto definido duas vezes em lugares diferentes.

## Interface

Isto é uso errado de interface, porque interface são capacidades de um objeto então algo que chama `ICliente` não é uma capacidade é a definição de um objeto, talvez fosse o caso de usar uma classe abstrata (infelizmente raro ter boas respostas sobre isso aqui).

Sugiro fortemente estudar mais (com profundidade, não apenas a superfície) o que é uma interface e o porquê de usá-la, [aqui tem algumas respostas boas sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interface?tab=Votes) (outras nem tanto, principalmente na internet tem muito conteúdo ruim que desensina, não sei porque as pessoas acham que tudo o que está na internet é confiável e às vezes questionam fontes fidedignas).

Você deve aceitar uma interface quando **só** precisa acessar os seus membros, quando precisa acessar outros membros então: ou precisa de outra interface; ou precisa acessar o objeto todo; ou ainda precisa ampliar o que a interface tem, o que dá até medo falar isto porque neste caso provavelmente seria outro erro.

Note que eles são compatíveis enquanto você usa a interface, quando resolve fazer o *cast* é que dá problema, mas o problema é mais embaixo conforme está dito acima.

Deu pra notar que só criou a interface para "agrupar" dois objetos que na verdade é um só? Essa interface nem deveria existir se não tivesse criado duas classes para representar o mesmo objeto.

## Conceituação

Sempre falo que orientação a objeto é difícil, e um dos motivos é porque ela não é sobre mecanismos como uso de interface, é sobre modelar certo e isso não costuma-se ensinar em lugar algum e sem o caso concreto quase sempre a pessoa faz errado (não dá para seguir receitas de bolo). Por isso é comum ter "trabalhão", está consertando os erros de modelagem.

O modelo deve ser ser único, canônico, DRY, inclusive para facilitar a manutenção. Não faz sentido ter uma coisa no que chama de "aplicação" e outro no que chama de "DLL", até porque essa DLL faz parte da aplicação. Colocar penduricalho na aplicação não solucionará o problema, apenas fará ele mais complicado.

[image: Tomada cheia de penduricalhos para ligar com o plug em vez de por direto]

Dá para perceber que tem outras conceituações erradas olhando apenas esse trecho, imagina vendo toda aplicação. Sem conceitos corretos ou erra sem perceber ou acerta por coincidência.

Por isso deve ter vários outros problemas que não geram erros na compilação. Funcionar é diferente de estar certo.

Comment: Obrigado pela aula! Ainda estou absorvendo o que você escreveu.
Só pra contextualizar melhor, essa DLL que eu coloquei como algo "fora da aplicação", funcionará como uma espécie de "plugin de acesso dados", e a aplicação (imutável) apenas consumiria os dados da DLL.

A DLL poderia: acessar uma API REST, um arquivo binário com formato exótico, um banco Sybase, etc.

Essa aplicação poderá utilizar qualquer das opções, apenas "trocando a DLL".
Por isso usei a interface: quis que a aplicação e a DLL tivessem um formato compatível entre elas. Vou estudar o assunto.

Comment: No momento que é usada pela aplicação ela faz parte da aplicação. POr isso que eu digo que está conceituado errado. Se a outra classe `Cliente` tem algo totalmente diferente deveria ter outro nome indiecando que aquilo não é um cliente e sim algo que pega dados de um cliente em "formato exótico". E aí para passar de um para o outro deveria copiar manualmente mesmo, pelo menos seria o caso normal (pode ser que em algum caso não precisaria, mas precisa entender a questão com muito mais profundidade). Note que a interface ainda seria errada porque não é a mesma funcionalidade.

Comment: Sim, entendi. Parte do problema eu resolvi acessando os objetos "via interface", sem cast (não sabia que dava, mas deu certo). Isso "funcionou" e atende em parte ao que eu preciso. Mas você me mostrou que é necessário reanalisar o sistema.
Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

A razão é muito simples: não se pode converter implicitamente dois objetos porque implementam a mesma interface, isso não garante que eles são iguais.
De uma outra maneira podemos dizer que, as duas classes **implementam** a mesma interface, e não **derivam** de um mesmo tipo, por isso nada garante que são "iguais" para se fazer um cast explícito assim.

Uma interface diz "o que deve ser implementado" para respeitar o contrato, mas não "que somente isso deve ser implementado", então você poderia simplesmente na classe Cliente da DLL adicionar uma propriedade `public int Abobrinha` e na outra classe Cliente `public string BlaBlaBla`, isso não iria ferir a implementação da interface e mostra o quanto as classes podem ser diferentes.

A interface garante o mínimo, então já sabe o que esperar daquela classe, daí fazer cast é outra coisa.

Respondendo sua pergunta, para eles serem compatíveis precisaria compartilhar uma classe em comum, o que iria tornar inválido o uso da interface, pois ai não estaria compartilhando um contrato, mas um tipo.
Pode usar para esses casos um *Mapper* que faça isso de maneira simples, como por exemplo o [Automapper](https://automapper.org/)

Ele mapeia facilmente objetos semelhantes (que tem mesmas propriedades e mesmos tipos), por exemplo que implementam a mesma interface, com o mínimo de código, acho que isso deve ajudar de forma simples nesse problema.

Um exemplo bem simples para o exemplo da sua classe seria:

```
public bool Salvar(ICliente objClienteApp)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<ICliente,Cliente>();

    var clienteMapeado = Mapper.Map<Cliente>(objClienteApp);
    ....
}
```

Comment: Obrigado. Vou testar e voltou aqui pra dizer se deu certo.

Comment: ok, qualquer dúvida deixe um comentário. Existem vários mappers gratuitos no mercado, citei o Automapper porque é bem conhecido e muito usado nesses casos :)